# Targeting certain element if no children

Tags: javascript, jquery, children

Something that I expected to be rather simple is causing me a lot of headache.

I am trying to check if the a certain element has children, if no children I would like to change the css for the next element `<i>` for that particular instance.

I have managed to get the script to remove all `<i>` elements but it should only remove it from those instances where there are no children found.

I normally manage to get my jquery working with a lot of trial/error, but with this one I'm in the dark even though it can't be very hard. It must be something rather simple I'm missing here.

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
    if ($('nav ul li').find('ul').length = 0) {
        $(this).next('i').css('display','none')
    }
});
```

HTML

```
<ul>
  <li>
    <input type="checkbox" checked>
        <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-chevron-down"></i>prime 1</a>
 </li>
 <li>
    <input type="checkbox" checked>
        <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-chevron-down"></i>prime 1</a>
              <ul>
                <li><a href="#">sub 1</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">sub 2</a></li>
              </ul>
 </li>
```

Comment: Can you post your HTML?

Comment: http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/sel_nthchild.asp use this and check if it returns something?

Comment: one note -- for comparison use `===` not `=`

Comment: I've added the HTML above

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because `this` inside the `if` block does not refer to the `li` element.

You can use the .not() filter method with :has() to do it like

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('nav ul li').not(':has(ul)').next('i').css('display', 'none');
});
```

Note: I think there is another problem since, `i` cannot be a sibling element of a `li` element

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/c2j5cd7L/1/ - The `i` is moved as a child of `li` rather than next sibling

Comment: I think this is a nice one. I would go for this one

Comment: Thanks a lot! works great, indeed a mistake on my side, i needed to move the <i> element out before it actually worked!